# Laravel 5.2 - Route authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create the auth class from laravel and now i would like to know how i can put the /register page only for users who login in system?

my routes are:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  //
  Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  Route::auth();
  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
  //Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
});
```

Comment: You can use middlewares for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authenticate url just add a `auth` middleware, that will work after logged in a user. Follow the code below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
   Route::get('/register', 'YourController@getRegister');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a middleware to filter the users.
In the case of authentication, there is a built-in middleware
called 'auth'
You can filter by middlewares in group as AnowarCst showed you
or in single routes like this:

```
Route::get('/register', [
           'middleware' => 'auth',
           'yourController@yourFunction'
           ]);
```

Read the docs to better understand
[MIDDLEWARE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).

Don't be scared, it's more simple than how it looks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this:

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
      $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['register', 'showRegistrationForm']]);
}
```

And my routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::Auth();

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
   Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
});
```

Thanks guys.